# Property-based type resolution in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Is it possible to override the type resolution using JSON.NET based on a property of the JSON object? Based on existing APIs, it looks like I need a way of accepting a `JsonPropertyCollection` and returning the `Type` to be created.

NOTE: I'm aware of the [TypeNameHandling attribute](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationSettings.html), but that adds a `$type` property. I do not have control over the source JSON.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would appear that this is handled by creating a custom [JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) and adding it to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` before deserialisation.

[nonplus](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/nonplus) has left a handy sample on the [JSON.NET discussions board](http://web.archive.org/web/20170905181744/http://json.codeplex.com:80/discussions/56031) on Codeplex. I've modified the sample to return custom `Type` and deferring to the default creation mechanism, rather than creating the object instance on the spot.

```
abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of objectType, based properties in the JSON object
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract Type GetType(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        Type targetType = GetType(objectType, jObject);

        // TODO: Change this to the Json.Net-built-in way of creating instances
        object target = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);

        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }
}
```

And here is the example usage (also updated as mentioned above):

```
class VehicleConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Vehicle>
{
    protected override Type GetType(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        var type = (string)jObject.Property("Type");
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Car":
                return typeof(Car);
            case "Bike":
                return typeof(Bike);
        }

        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
            "The given vehicle type {0} is not supported!", type));
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the unimplemented abstract `WriteJson` method?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu You will want to override the property CanWrite and set it to false. This will have the converter fall back to its default behavior.